# Message: element not interactable in Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I would like to click on load more button to show all 347 products, however it returns
Message: element not interactable, any idea how can i fix it?

[load more button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLOKF.jpg)

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Chrome('e:/Users/fungc1/Documents/chromedriver.exe')
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
options=Options()


url= "https://www.toysrus.com.sg/lego"
driver.get(url)

while True:
    try:
                                        
        btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[name()='use' and @*='#chevron-circle-thin']")
        btn.click()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        break
```

Comment: You are grabbing a tag inside the `<svg>` tag which is the button picture.  What you need to click is the `<button>` tag that contains the `<svg>`.

Comment: Do you really need Selenium for this?  The `<button>` tag for the next page just fires a single URL.  You could do another request for that.

Comment: change your xpath to this - `//div[@class='show-more']/button`

Comment: When i change the xpath to be //div[@class='show-more']/button , it says element not interactable

Comment: Message: element click intercepted: Element <button class="btn" data-url="https://www.toysrus.com.sg/on/demandware.store/Sites-ToysRUs_SG-Site/en_SG/Search-UpdateGrid?cgid=lego&amp;start=96&amp;sz=96">...</button> is not clickable at point (508, 657). Other element would receive the click: <div class="inner">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.212)

Comment: Do you just want the product names?

Answer (score 1):

The thing is you would need to scroll till end of page to let selenium know where is the button in view point.

**Code :**

```
driver.get("https://www.toysrus.com.sg/lego/")
sleep(5)
driver.execute_script("var scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement || document.body);scrollingElement.scrollTop = scrollingElement.scrollHeight;")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn[data-url*='www.toysrus.com']"))).click()
print("Clicked on ")
```

**Update 1 :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\***\\Desktop\\Selenium+Python\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get("https://www.toysrus.com.sg/lego/")

while True:
    try:
        sleep(5)
        driver.execute_script("var scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement || document.body);scrollingElement.scrollTop = scrollingElement.scrollHeight;")
        sleep(5)
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn[data-url*='www.toysrus.com']"))).click()
        print("Clicked on ")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: Message: element click intercepted: Element <button class="btn" data-url="https://www.toysrus.com.sg/on/demandware.store/Sites-ToysRUs_SG-Site/en_SG/Search-UpdateGrid?cgid=lego&amp;start=96&amp;sz=96">...</button> is not clickable at point (509, 124). Other element would receive the click: <div class="modal country-switcher show" data-popup-country-selector="" data-write-country-to-cookie="SG" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="country-switcher-modal" aria-modal="true" style="padding-right: 16px; display: block;">...</div>

Comment: Well it works perfectly fine in my machine. `"C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe" C:/Users/etc/PycharmProjects/SeleniumSO/SOProblems.py
Clicked on 

Process finished with exit code 0
`

Comment: Did you remove the sleep ?

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/K2gzoLh.jpg   my screen capture here

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/K2gBxB3.jpg     the error is: Message: element click intercepted: Element <button class="btn" data-url="https://www.toysrus.com.sg/on/demandware.store/Sites-ToysRUs_SG-Site/en_SG/Search-UpdateGrid?cgid=lego&amp;start=96&amp;sz=96">...</button> is not clickable at point (509, 124). Other element would receive the click: <div class="modal country-switcher show" data-popup-country-selector="" data-write-country-to-cookie="SG" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="country-switcher-modal" aria-modal="true" style="padding-right: 16px; display: block;">...</div>

Comment: no you need to maximize your screen size also just after launching the website `driver.maximize_window()`

Comment: still not working https://pasteboard.co/K2gF9zZ.jpg

Comment: I have uploaded the anaconda jupter notebook in google drive: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/1/folders/1JkyIvrFYPLd9x5PRDXwyOagc_pX09k9a

Comment: thhanks for your help but now it only show 192 products, how to click few times until it show 347 products?

Comment: @BestBetty : make it in loop ?

Comment: @BestBetty : Check it out the Update1 code, it will click on that desired button till all the elements on UI have been shown.

Answer (score 0):

```
wait=WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

url= "https://www.toysrus.com.sg/lego"
driver.get(url)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".affirm.btn.btn-outline-secondary"))).click()
while True:
    try:
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='show-more']/button"))).click()
        time.sleep(5)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        break
```

You should replace time.sleep() for the visibility of the spinner. But just wait for the elements to load in.

```
allProducts=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='product-grid-wrapper']//div[@class='card product-tile product']")
print(len(allProducts))
```

Prints 346?

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/K2hb0c9.jpg  Can you take a look why 96/346 product printed, not 346/346 ?

Comment: You grabbed the values prior to show more.

Comment: i dont understand your answer, somehow i found the reason why it shows 96 product, it is because even the button is clicked for a few times, the view-source:https://www.toysrus.com.sg/lego/  will only have the first 96 product, do you know how can i fix it

Comment: I don't see where your grabbing the values after the button click.

Comment: it starts from : for item in toc:    can you go to the following link to view my notebook in anaconda  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EeZ1_mWHHh49m48Tmj1ffZAIdYc9b4wJ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: well you placed it on top so it always gets 96 the starting value.

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/K2i9arg.jpg  i try to put the code at the bottom but still show 96?